# How to get all forms in a windows form application

Tags: winforms

I have a windows form application.
I want to get all of form that application has, but i just found about the function Application.OpenForms. 
This function return all of forms are opening.
But I want to get all of forms in that application.
Is there any functions to get but not add to FormsColection for new Form created like this solution https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815707 ?
Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get list of all forms of my application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743303/how-to-get-list-of-all-forms-of-my-application)

Comment: thank you, that topic i don't find the solution because i want to get from a library! may you give me a suggestion?
thank you very much!

Comment: OpenForms tracks the *objects* you created.  If you want the *types* you wrote then you must use Reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"All of the forms that an application has" typically would mean using reflection for all of the types in the assembly that inherit from the `Windows.Forms.Form` class.

The `Application.OpenForms` only tracks forms that are opened, not necessarily those that have been instantiated and not opened.

What you really need to do is track all of the forms when the form objects are instantiated.  See code below:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Globals.InstantiatedForms.Add(Me)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Module Globals
    Public InstantiatedForms As New List(Of Windows.Forms.Form)
End Module
```